# How to get the specified Product name in EditText box?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autofill

I am developing an android application. In that application I have some variety of products.
When user clicks on any product it will show images of the product. In that page only I have 
one Button like Enquiry. When user clicks on that it will open a form page . In that form I have one field Product name. After completing this when user clicks on submit the details has been mailed to admin mail .

What I want is when user clicks on Enquiry Button it should open a form page with auto filled 
product name .

Here is my code.

Lenovo.java:

```
        Button order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order);

        order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View view){

                Intent intentmenu = new Intent(view.getContext(),Order.class);

                startActivityForResult(intentmenu,0);

                }

            });
    }
```

**Order.java:**

```
        final EditText name   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);

        final EditText mail   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

        final EditText phone   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);

        final EditText product   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.product);


        final String _name = name.getText().toString();

        final String _mail = mail.getText().toString();

        final String _phone = phone.getText().toString();

        final String _product = product.getText().toString();

        System.out.println(_name);

        System.out.println(_mail);

        System.out.println(_phone);

        System.out.println(_product);

        Button email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        email.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){     

                  public void onClick(View v){


                      StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

                      body.append("Name: "+name.getText().toString());

                      body.append("\n\n\nMail: "+mail.getText().toString());

                      body.append("\n\n\nPhone: "+phone.getText().toString());

                      body.append("\n\n\nProduct: "+product.getText().toString());


                      Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                      i.setType("text/plain");

                      i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  ,new String[]

                      {"b.gadwantikar1@gmail.com","",});

                      i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Customer Details");

                      i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.toString());

                      startActivity(i);

                      finish();


                  }

        });

    }
}
```

If any body knows then help me out...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you add only relevant parts of the code? It's difficult to go through everything. You will find more people answering your question that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below:

- Add new activity to your project
- add the new activity to your Mainfest file.
- add new XML file for the new activity into layout folder.
- in the XML file define TextView and/or Edittext as your demand.
- setContentView of your new activity in onCreate() method to be the new XML file.
- Start the new Activity by the following code wich will have the data that will transfer to the new activity.

like the following:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,NewActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("Key","data_need_to_Be Transfer");
startActivity(intent);
```

and to retrive the data that already trsansfered to the new activity by doing:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String yourString=intent.getStringExtra("key");
and then you can assig the value of that string to Textview or EditText
```

Comment: could you please specify for me what did you do so far?

Comment: in your case I think this coed will work: String yourString=intent.getStringExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);